# I want to use an ADODB Conection in ms-access vba and I dont know what library to activate for it works

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to use an ADODB Conection in ms-access VBA, but it doesn't recognize the syntax.

I think is a library but I don't know which one to activate it

I show the screenshot of the error.

[screenshot with syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiGBp.png)

Can somebody help me with the library name?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to add a reference to the ADODB library. Cf. https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/30609/how-to-use-adodb-connection-in-vba-

Answer (score 2):

Try using

Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X LIbrary

In my version ms acces 2016 it's version 6.1

[image: Window with the llibrery]